# How to prepare iOS 4.2 app from Xcode 3.2 for iPhone 5 support?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, submit, iphone-5

I have this app that I wrote more than 1,5 year ago. It was my first project in iOS, so I was working on wht was given to me - in this case it was Xcode 3.2 and iOS 4.2. Now I want to submit this app to AppStore, but thing is that as of 1st May Apple requires developers to support new iPhone 5 screen resolution and as a result also I have to provide iPhone 5 screens for submitting proces.

Any advice how to solve this situation? Rewriting all classes with screen bounds or throw it away and use Xcode 4.2 or change for iOS 5.0 and develop "same" app under Xcode 4.2? Or maybe another way?

To anitcipate some answers, I cannot upgrade higher than Xcode 4.2, because I'm working on Snow Leopard and what's more painful I don't have iPhone 5 itself, so I'm not even able to test it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not, you will need the iOS 6 SDK to support the 4" iOS device.

Update to either Lion or Mountain Lion and then download the latest SDK and make sure that you autoresize masks are set correctly and your app will work on 3,5" and 4" device.

Comment: but shouldn't it run on iPhone 5?

Comment: Yes, apps build with a previous version of the iOS SDK will run but not in 4" mode, which Apple requiers all apps to do now. For supporting the 4" devices you will need the iOS 6 SDK.

Comment: am I able to use Xcode 4.2 with imported iOS 6 SDK for that purpose? So I can i.e. modify layout depending on `screenBounds`? Or is upgrading Mac and Xcode a "must-do"?

Comment: As long as you build with the iOS 6 SDK you should be alright. But modifying the layout based on the `screenBounds` sounds like a lot of work. Why not just let the auto resize mask solve that issue for you.

Comment: well, isn't that great :/ do you know how to provide iPhone 5 screens without the device or Xcode with iPhone5 simulator? :/ let's assume that I would use Xcode 4.2 and iOS SDK6 but still I don't have anything to prepare screen shots

Comment: You will need to have the full iOS 6 SDK with the simulator, if do not have this you are just out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will have to update to a newer version of XCode, which will require an update of your OS to either Lion or Mountain Lion. I tried doing this recently with an older Macbook that I had, and it became more of a headache to get it to work with the older software than switching to a new SDK.

Everything should be a relatively easy update.

Comment: but is it possible to get screen from simulator for iPhone 5 without device and using xcode 4.2/snow leopard? importing from xcode 4.5 simulator6.0 didn't work - hung my xcode :/

Comment: I don't believe you will unfortunately. From the last sentence here it seems you tried to take your project from 4.2 and put it into 4.5 and run it, is that correct?

Comment: nope, I'm using Snow Leopard on which I have Xcode 4.2 (with imported from dmg files of various Xcodes versions folders of SDK for different iOS's). Now I want to submit an app which was originally wrote under iOS 4.2 and Xcode 3.2, but now I have problem how to get iPhone 5 screens - don't have neither iPhone 5 nor Xcode better than 4.2

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I think you are out of luck here. The only option I could think of is find a buddy who has a newer version of OS X or XCode that you trust and have him run it to get screen shots and to submit. Sorry